# Lost power in kitchen ceiling fan, guest bathroom,guest bedroom

Tags: electrical

I've lost power in part of house .all breakers have 120v .it starts from kitchen ceiling fan to living room wall,guest bathroom,guest bedroom.just lights.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird Power Outage in Certain Rooms- Condominium](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/178240/weird-power-outage-in-certain-rooms-condominium)

Comment: As the duplicate notes, you've almost certainly lost one leg of your electrical feed. Call your utility to report it.

Comment: @Machavity: OP claims that all breakers have 120v. If this is accurate then problem is not a lost leg, but must be downstream from the service panel.

Comment: Are you stating that multiple circuits have lost power?

Comment: Haven't lost any in panel.120v going through all breakers.

Comment: Clarification on my question, the fixtures that are not working, are they on one circuit or multiple circuits?

Comment: Hi, you need to provide a LOT more information for anyone to help.  How many different breakers feed the  various light fixtures involved?  Did it used to work, and if so was there any sort of event - lightning, etc ?  How are you determining that the breakers' outputs are truly 120V -- relative to Earth Ground, or to neutral returns, etc?